# Flagging Duplicates, etc

Tags: feature-request

Can you provide something simple to indicate that a question is a duplicate while still in the Questions Page list?

I like to answer questions, but sometimes I go into a question to provide an answer and then I find out it is marked as a duplicate and I can not answer it.

It would be great if the question in the list would tell me that it was a duplicate so I didn't bother going into the question, since I can't answer it any more.

Comment: What list? The main page? Questions page? Search results? Review history? Votes history?

Comment: Sorry: The questions page

Comment: It *does* indicate questions that are closed as a duplicate.  It says, "[duplicate]" at the end of those questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This already exists:

[image: Duplicate]

However, if it was closed just a couple of seconds/minutes ago, this will probably not shown due to [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).